# On Affliation change using MucAdmin() gives forbidden(403) Error in asmack android

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

First I change owner affliation to administrator by revokeOwnership() nad than I try revokeAdmin() but it's not working,than I try following method for change admin affliation to none

when I call following method at time of leave group gives forbidden(403) Error,How to solve this Error and set admin affliation none in muc.

```
private void changeAffiliationByAdmin(String jid, String affiliation,String grpnm) throws XMPPException 
{
         MUCAdmin iq = new MUCAdmin();
         iq.setTo(grpnm + "@conference." + Utils.SERVER_NAME);
         iq.setType(IQ.Type.SET);


         MUCAdmin.Item item = new MUCAdmin.Item(affiliation,null);
         item.setJid(jid + "@" + Utils.SERVER_NAME);
         iq.addItem(item);

         // Wait for a response packet back from the server.
         filter = new PacketIDFilter(iq.getPacketID());
         PacketCollector response = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
         // Send the change request to the server.


         connection.sendPacket(iq);
         // Wait up to a certain number of seconds for a reply.
         MUCAdmin answer = (MUCAdmin) response.nextResult(SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());
         // Stop queuing results
         response.cancel();


         if (answer == null) {
             throw new XMPPException("No response from server.");
         }
         else if (answer.getError() != null) {
             throw new XMPPException(answer.getError());
         }
     }
```

if i user this code for change owner affliation to none than it's not woking,

```
MUCOwner iq = new   MUCOwner();
        iq.setTo(grpnm + "@conference." + Utils.SERVER_NAME);
        iq.setType(IQ.Type.SET);

        System.out.println("before affliation changed" + jid + grpnm);
        // Set the new affiliation.
          MUCOwner.Item item = new  MUCOwner.Item(affiliation,null);
        item.setJid(jid + "@" + Utils.SERVER_NAME);
        iq.addItem(item);

        System.out.println("after affliation changed" + jid + grpnm);

        // Wait for a response packet back from the server.
        filter = new PacketIDFilter(iq.getPacketID());
        PacketCollector response = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
        // Send the change request to the server.

        System.out.println("call IQ packet" + jid + grpnm);
        connection.sendPacket(iq);
        // Wait up to a certain number of seconds for a reply.
          IQ answer = (IQ) response.nextResult(SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());
        // Stop queuing results
        response.cancel();

        if (answer == null) {
            throw new XMPPException("No response from server.");
        }
        else if (answer.getError() != null) {
            throw new XMPPException(answer.getError());
        }
```

Comment: It seems you are not owner of the MUC room you are trying to reconfigure, no ?

Comment: first i change owner affliation to administrator by revokeownership() method and than I try to change admin affliation to none by this code but it gives me 403 error...